# Show only a fragment from stream

Tags: ios, stream, vlc, libvlc

I am wondering if there is a possibility to show only a fragment of a video stream. Let's say we have a video 1920x1024 and I want to show only a rect from 0,0 to 600,400.
Can I achieve this? What kind of libraries can do that? I tried to find something in VLC but i did not find anything.

Something similar to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nNoUDH2k3Y

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this yes, however I am not quite sure if you can achieve exactly the same dynamic cropping effect shown in the video you linked to.

For VLC the term ***crop*** is what you're looking for. The [wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Crop/) is quite minimal, however it should get you started. Otherwise check out the command line help (vlc -H) and look for the crop and padd parameters.

An example crop such as in your case 0,0 600,400 would be achieved through the video filter named croppadd or the vout filter crop (depending on your VLC version and platform)

```
vlc $video_input --sout='#transcode{vcodec=XXX,vb=XXX,fps=XX.X,width=1920,height=1024,vfilter=croppadd{croptop=0,cropbottom=624,cropleft=0,cropright=1320}}:standard{access=XXX,mux=XX,dst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX}'
```

vfilter

```
vfilter=croppadd{croptop=0,cropbottom=624,cropleft=0,cropright=1320}
```

Another way to use it as stated in the wiki

```
vlc $video_input --video-filter=croppadd --croppadd-croptop=0 --croppadd-cropbottom=624 --croppadd-cropleft=0 --croppadd-cropright=1320
```

For the library VLC wise it would be ***libvlc*** and the corresponding LibVLC video controls get and set_crop_geometry - See this link for the [SDK](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__video.html).

Maybe this leads you in the right directions. It certainly depends on your setup. Are you scripting and restranscoding a video stream or are you trying to integrate a library into your code.